# If console application is running longer than expected then email to developer

Tags: c#, email, alert

I am having a console application written in c#, which is scheduled to run every 1 hr .

The application normally takes less than 10 min .

If the application is running more than 15 min I want to receive an email from the application with out breaking the code .

what is the best way to start with the minimum code .

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  Do you have a more specific example of what you're looking for?   Also, can you show some code demonstrating what you've tried thus far?  Otherwise, people will down-vote and the question will probably be closed as "too broad"

Comment: You could start a timer with the interval set to 15 minutes. In the tick event you could write code which sends an email, and then turns the timer off.

Comment: I agree with @Ralt -- Timer is the easiest way to solve this.

Comment: @Ralt post that as an answer.

Comment: should time be in separate thread?

Comment: @MladenOršolić Depends which Timer you use. I'm sure it's only the Forms.Timer that runs on the UI thread. System.Timer fires it's elapsed on another thread, and Threading.Timer is definitely threaded. Since it's a console app he'll use one of the latter two anyway.

Comment: @Ralt got this right . that what I am exactly looking for.

Comment: Thanks @roryap this is my first question , from the next time I will keep the points you made  .Thanks.

Comment: @mbg -- Please edit *this* question accordingly.  Don't wait for "next time".

Comment: @mbg You should mark it as correct so the question can be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a timer in your constructor

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

public static void Main()
{        
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 15;  //1 second * 60 seconds in a minute * 15 minutes
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

And then in the time elapsed event run your code which sends an email

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   //Code which sends an email
   aTimer.Enabled = false;     
}
```

Comment: Can you, from separate timer thread, know if the code is still running in main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Make a timer that runs for 15 minutes.

After the period Ends, it should check for a condition (finished, yes no)
if not finished -> mail.